# Weird thing when checking sessions in Rails on POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, request, csrf

I'm having a weird error in Rails, I'm making an app where users can log in and upload files. Everything works, but when I want to upload any file, the code in my application controller for checking an active session fails because it can't access the session array:

```
def current_user
    if session[:session].nil? # <- Fails here
        redirect_to "/login"  
    else
        if session[:hash] == Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(session[:password]+" - "+session[:username]+" - "+session[:uuid]) #< and here (removing the other if) with NoMethodError
            return 0
        else
            redirect_to "/login"

        end

    end
end
```

This works on other things, but apparently breaks on POST requests. This is my HAML view to upload files:

```
%b Upload

%form{:action=>"/u",:method=>"post",:enctype=>"multipart/form-data"}
    %br
    %input{:type=>"file",:name=>"file"}
    %input{:type=>"submit",:value=>"Upload"}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Also in POST requests I get in the app log: `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently I had to add this:

```
%input{:type=>"hidden", :name=>"authenticity_token", :value=>form_authenticity_token.to_s}
```

to my HAML form, now everything works good and no more `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` :)

Comment: Hmm the problem there is that you haven't used the Rails helper. You are using just plain HAML there.

Comment: The authenticity token is automatically generated if you use the rails helpers.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that anyone with the html can now see your auth token?  And thus log in as you?  Wouldn't this be a huge security risk?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the Authenticity Token that is generated by Rails to avoid Cross-Site Forgery. Check the HTML code generate to be sure the token is generated, if it's not, thats the problem, because Rails 3 default behaviour when the token is missing or doesn't match is to reset the session.

EDIT: Hmm the problem there is that you haven't used the Rails helper. You are using just plain HAML there.

Comment: In my application layout I have this: `= csrf_meta_tags`. This only seems to happen when I do a POST request

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone decide to use html helper inside  the form:

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag('authenticity_token', form_authenticity_token.to_s)%>
```